# Can't use a value of data object inside another value in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I want to use a value in data object inside another value. When I try the code below:

```
data(){
   return {
      firstname: 'Shadi',
      greeting: 'hello' + firstname
   }
}
```

I get an error that firstname is not defined. When I use the code below:

```
data(){
       return {
          firstname: 'Shadi',
          greeting: 'hello' + this.firstname
       }
    }
```

the error is not shown but the firstname is replaced undefined. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Self-references in object literals / initializers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616202/self-references-in-object-literals-initializers)

Comment: That link is for javascript; the question is about Vuejs, which does use JS but in this case it isn't the same syntax

Comment: Yes syntax is different. Actually both your answers are related somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a computed hook:

```
data(){
       return {
          firstname: 'Shadi'
      }
},    
computed: {
        greeting: function () {
            return 'hello' + this.firstname;
        }
```

Comment: Your answer works fine for me. but Im sure this is the right answer or not.

Comment: There is no "right answer" - if it helped you the most, you can select it as the right answer. Upvotes are for other people to show which answer helped them.